# Thread 1: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS on MFMailComposeViewController's dismissModalViewController (tried iOS 5.1 , 5 , 4.3)

Tags: iphone, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, exc-bad-access

Ok, this has been haunting me for a while now...

I have checked and all the other questions/answers are with non ARC projects.

Whenever I present the MFMCvc and I quickly cancel the message I get the Thread1:EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error message on iPhones.  Works fine on the iPad or if I let it sit for a bit (say 30 secs or more)

Any advise?  (other than putting a timer and not dismissing until timer's up?)

BTW I'm doing the same with MFMessageComposeViewController and it works fine on both iPhone and iPad.

Here is my code to present it

```
if (([action isEqualToString:@"EMail"]) && contact.length>0)
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        [mailViewController setSubject:@""];
        [mailViewController setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
        [mailViewController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:contact]];
        [mailViewController setMailComposeDelegate:self];
        [self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:NO];
    }
}
```

And here is where I dismiss it

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
    {
        switch (result)
        {
            case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Send EMail" message:@"EMail Has Been Cancelled"
                                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];
            }
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            {
                NSLog(@"Error");
            }
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Send EMail" message:@"EMail Has Been Sent"
                                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];
            }
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Send EMail" message:@"EMail Has Been Saved"
                                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];
            }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
```

Comment: My apologies, I was adding it but I had to get code on my PC so I could copy/paste it. Also notice it works on MFMessageComposeViewController. I need to login to stackoverflow from my MAC...

Comment: Seems ok, enable NSZombies and check if any other library is doing something strange http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, looking for the "Variables to be set in the environment" to add NSZombieEnabled

Comment: Ok, for those of you who are wondering where the "Zombies" are in XCode 4.3.2, it's under Product / Edit Scheme under Run (your app) / Diagnostics and on Objective-C there is a checkbox "Enable Zombie Objects"

Comment: This is interesting:  2012-05-18 12:44:30.462 MyApp[####:#####] *** -[MFMailComposeController actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8a886b0

Comment: Check wich object is 0x8a886b0. Is it your MFMailComposeViewController object?

Comment: I don't think I have that object (at least not in my MFMailCompVC object.  I tried to NSLog(@"%@",self) before and after the present and before and after the dismiss and all 4 had the same id, but not the one in the error messsage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Doesn't the line: `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];` - need to be: `[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];`?  You are wanting to dismiss the MFMailComposeViewController.

2) There may also be an issue with the MFMailComposeViewController not being retained. When I've used this class I've created a property for the controller. This might be worth trying.

```
// in the interface definition
 @property (nonatomic, strong) MFMailComposeViewController* mailComposer;
```

and then

```
// at creation time
if (([action isEqualToString:@"EMail"]) && contact.length>0)

if(![MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) return; // bail early if can't send mail

MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mailViewController setSubject:@""];
[mailViewController setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
[mailViewController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:contact]];
[mailViewController setMailComposeDelegate:self];
[self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:NO];

[self setMailComposer: mailViewController];
// if not using ARC then:  [mailViewController release];
```

and then in the didFinish

```
 [[self mailComposer] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 [self setMailComposer: nil];
```

Comment: Agreed, the issue could be that `mailController` is not being retained

Comment: Tried to dismiss with controller but that didn't work so I created the property as advised and it worked.  What puzzles me is why this behavior?  It works fine on the iPad...?  :O

Comment: saved my life today, thanks! creating a property to keep it retained did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Move **[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]** to the top of your didFinishWithResult function. In other words, dismiss the mail view before showing the alert view. I'm not sure if this will eliminate your crash, but regardless, you should do this.

Comment: Tried it but still crashing  :(